# @ObservedObject not publishing changes to View

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `View` with a `Text` that is meant to be updated based on a `CountDown()` value `secondsLeft`:

```
struct TimerCapsule: View {
    @ObservedObject var countdown = CountDown()
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(self.countdown.secondsLeft)")
            .font(.system(size: 30))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 40)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 15, bottom: 5, trailing: 15))
            .background(
                Capsule()
                    .fill(Color("Exit"))
                    .opacity(0.7)
            )
            .onAppear{
                print("Start countdown")
                self.countdown.start(from: 30)
            }
            .onDisappear {
                self.countdown.stop()
            }
    }
}
```

Here is the `CountDown` class below. `print("Seconds left: \(self.secondsLeft)")` successfully prints 30, 29, 28 etc - however, this is not updated in the `View` above. There is only 1 instance been used in the view above so I'm not sure why it is not being reflected in the `Text("\(self.countdown.secondsLeft)")` above.

Timer:

```
class CountDown: ObservableObject {
    @Published var secondsLeft = 30
    @ObservedObject var block = Block()
    var timer: Timer!
    func start(from seconds: Int){
        self.secondsLeft = seconds
        print("start timer")
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true){ _ in
            if (self.secondsLeft == 1){
                switch self.block.type {
                case .match:
                    self.block.pass()
                case .pass:
                    self.block.pass()
                default:
                    self.block.delete()
                }
            }
            self.secondsLeft -= 1
            print("Seconds left: \(self.secondsLeft)")
        }
    }
    func stop(){
        self.timer?.invalidate()
    }
}
```

Any idea?

EDIT:

**ContentView.swift**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var auth = UserAuth()
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if auth.uid != nil { HomeView(auth: auth) } else { LoginView(auth: auth) }
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeView.swift**

```
struct HomeView: View {
    let auth: UserAuth
    @ObservedObject var block = Block()
    init(auth: UserAuth) {
        self.auth = auth
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orange
        UITabBar.appearance().unselectedItemTintColor = UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        UITabBar.appearance().autoresizesSubviews = true
    }
    @State var selectedTab = 1
    @ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()
        
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            TabView(selection: $selectedTab) {
                Settings(auth: auth)
                .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "gear")
                    Text("Settings")
    
                }.tag(0)
                ZStack {
                    MapView(locationManager: locationManager)
                    Color.black.opacity(self.block.status.opacity).animation(nil)
                    VStack {
                    if self.block.type == Type.match || self.block.type == Type.pass {
                        VStack{
                            TimerCapsule()
                        }.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                    }
                        Spacer()
                        if self.block.type == Type.create || self.block.type == Type.delete || self.block.type == Type.pass{
                        StatusButton()
                        }
                    }.padding(40)
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "location.circle.fill")
                    Text("Home")
                }.tag(1)
                ProfileView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person")
                    Text("Profile")
                }.tag(2)
            }.accentColor(Color.white)
            .font(.headline)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you show what is `Block`? I feel the reason is there, because it works after removing everything related to it.

Comment: When I paste the `TimerCapsule()` contents to where `TimerCapsule()` is in the view - the Countdown works... @Asperi - so block isn't related

Comment: I've deleted all references of `Block()` in both view and model @Asperi

Answer (score 0):

Can't reproduce any issue. You didn't give enough information to allow the entire code to compile, but if we remove references to all the stuff you left out, we get this:

```
class CountDown: ObservableObject {
    @Published var secondsLeft = 30
    var timer: Timer!
    func start(from seconds: Int){
        self.secondsLeft = seconds
        print("start timer")
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true){ _ in
            // don't know what Block is
            self.secondsLeft -= 1
            print("Seconds left: \(self.secondsLeft)")
        }
    }
    func stop(){
        self.timer?.invalidate()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var countdown = CountDown()
    var body: some View {
        Text("\(self.countdown.secondsLeft)")
            .font(.system(size: 30))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .frame(width: 100, height: 40)
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 5, leading: 15, bottom: 5, trailing: 15))
            .background(
                Capsule()
                    .fill(Color(.black)) // don't know what Exit is
                    .opacity(0.7)
            )
            .onAppear{
                print("Start countdown")
                self.countdown.start(from: 30)
            }
            .onDisappear {
                self.countdown.stop()
            }
    }
}
```

Copy and paste that into a new SwiftUI project and you'll see that the text does count down.

So if something is preventing that from happening, it's something you didn't show.

Comment: Yes you're right, I copy-pasted `TimerCapsule()` in `ContentView` and it worked fine. However I'm not sure what the problem is when it's in my `HomeView` (I've added my full code above). I removed all references to `block` and it didn't change anything so don't think it's that.

Comment: Yes but I answered the question you asked based on the code you gave. It was up to you to be honest about your code.

Comment: Yeah apologies - I should have added the full code. Wasn't sure if it was needed.